# The best way to reach an inverse function

Tags: function, functional-programming, f#, functor

Given a function type

```
type Func<'a> = 'a -> 'a
```

how to develop map function for `Func`?

---

I have an idea

```ml
let fmap (f : 'b -> 'a) (g : 'a -> 'b) (l : Func<'a>) : Func<'b> = f >> l >> g
```

but this realization has `g` and inverse function `f`.

Is possible to create a function with one transformation function (`f` or `g`)?

Comment: No, it's not possible, since `Func<'a>` uses `a` in a contravariant position. (That is called `Endo a` in Haskell, by the way)

Comment: It is generally not possible to automatically produce an inverse of a given function, because it may not exist, or there may be more than just one. For example, what is the inverse of `fun x -> 42`? It's kind of like division by zero.

Comment: Indeed it is generally not possible. It [_is_ possible (-ish) in special cases](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1480904), but that's rather off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: That seems to be a special case of a Profunctor `F a b` where `a = b`. Indeed, your `fmap` function body is identical to [`dimap`](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpPlus/blob/e33fd4f3bea1160e3f769438a933d9b0813d97d9/src/FSharpPlus/Functor.fs#L544) if you take out the type annotations.